# How to manage mysql tables relationships  with date thing

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have this scenario

User can have many profiles per year and i also want to keep history as well

I have following tables

1. User
2. Profile

Now i am confused should i make separate table for year.

I am confused to make separate profile per year.

I mean when the new year comes then i would want to copy the profile to new profile so that they can edit the new profile but previous year profile will remain uneditable

Comment: My website keeps a history of users and their actions as well. I solved this with a fact table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema. This may or may not suit your needs, but it helped me a lot.

Comment: i like that star schema , i want to know that does all the attribute of date table is stored as integers??

Comment: No, you can store the valuables as anything you like. Basically a Star Schema is a table with a Primary Key (of course), a timestamp (which in your case can be just an integer "year"), and Foreign Keys to all relevant tables. At least, that's how I use it in order to keep histories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have one table for profiles. Each profile should have a creation date. Then you can sort by date and make the newest profile editable, and treat the older ones as archives.

Comment: You'll probably want a compound index on this to avoid filesort when you're selecting user + date from the Profile table.

Comment: can you please explain what is compound index , i didn't understand what u mean

Comment: A compound index is like a regular index, but it combines information from more than one column. Don't worry about it too much, you can always add an index later if you want to improve performance.